# How to be able to select the text but not the textbox

Tags: vb.net

This seems like it would be pretty simple but I can't figure out a way to do it and there isn't a solution anywhere on the internet that I can find leading me to believe it isn't possible using this language.

I have a simple program, you give it input, hit a button and it outputs into a textbox.

I had to make it a textbox and not a label because you can't highlight the text in a label, which is necessary for the user to be able to copy the text. However, as a textbox, the user can select the box. I've set it to ReadOnly, so they can't type in it, but the blinking text cursor is still there if the box is clicked on and it looks really bad. I've also tried setting Enabled to False, but then the text can't be highlighted.

The textbox itself shouldn't be able to be selected, just the text inside the textbox.

How do I do such a thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

P/Invoke is the only method I know of.

```
<System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")> _
Private Shared Function HideCaret(hWnd As IntPtr) As Boolean
End Function

Private Sub TextBox1_GotFocus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.GotFocus
    HideCaret(TextBox1.Handle)
End Sub
```

Here is documentation on the user32.dll HideCaret function:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648403(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Ah that makes more sense, I was like "... that's not VB.net"

Comment: Yeah, Had to swipe it from a C# project I had handy before I realized you were looking for VB.  Hopefully the conversion will work for you.

Comment: You may need to call this in the focus event for the control, I can't remember if it sticks between changing controls or not.

Comment: Yeah, I'm having a little trouble figuring out where to put those. it warns me that the function doesn't return a value, which I know it shouldn't but I don't know where in my code to put the Public Sub.

Comment: The DllImport should be put someplace common, I usually make a `Win32` class to hold all my api calls.  I think you would then just call `Win32.HideCaret` in the `.GotFocus` event of the textbox.

Comment: It's working for me in a quick test.  Are you sure you didn't accidentally leave the textbox disabled or in some other state from previous experiments?

Comment: Yeah, I had it disabled, I figured that out pretty quick and deleted the comment. Anyway, if I call `Win32.HideCaret` in the `.GotFocus` sub for my button it tells me `'Win32' is not declared`. And if I just call `HideCaret()` it tells me it's missing the parameter for hWnd.

Comment: You can place the DllImport directly in the form if you want, then You can call it directly as in my updated example code.  I only recommended moving it to it's own Win32 class to make it available in a central location, but that's entirely optional.

Comment: Okay, I've got it exactly (well, not exactly, I entered the name of my own textbox) like you have in your update, I even added `Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices` so VB.net would recognized `DLLimport`. Now there are no errors but it still doesn't hide the cursor/caret.

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much, I was stupid, I accidentally had the `.Gotfocus` event bound to the wrong control.

Comment: Also, add `Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices` to the top of your code, VB.net won't recognize `DLLimport` without it.

Comment: I approached this in another way which I thought I would share. I had a textbox and a small button which would copy to clipboard. This way users would not have to focus into the textbox, select the text and then either right click and copy or use a keyboard shortcut... (I know that you can have some jscript that will select all text on focus)... but just click the button which is much easier.